# Query last 15 records from table but include data from a related table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `users` and `videos`. Each video is related to a particular user who uploaded them.

I would like to display the last 15 videos with the user who uploaded them by selecting these columns: `username` from `users` and `name, thumbnail, type, quality, title_id, updated_at` from `videos`

Here are the columns in my `users` table:

[image]

Here are the columns in my `videos` table:

[image]

This is what I've written so far:

```
SELECT * FROM `videos`,`users` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after but I suspect you want to `JOIN` the tables and then the `ORDER BY id` will work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the schema or better yet the create table statements for both the `users` and `videos` tables and better explain what you expect the results of your query to contain. ie, are you trying to get the last 15 videos posted by/belonging to a user? etc...

Comment: @WesleySmith 
Hello, this is exactly what I am looking for, show the last 15 videos and link them to the user who uploaded them

Comment: Gotcha, we can help with that. Could you please show use what columns are in your two tables?

Comment: @WesleySmith
Ok, I just need to connect them to the sample table users, contains only the username, in the video sample contains only video, img

So what action do I need to enter to connect the two tables (it does not matter what their contents are, only the connection matters)

But these are pictures from the database:
https://prnt.sc/uokju7 - video

https://prnt.sc/uokkol - users

Comment: I've edited your question to be more concise and include your comments. Please update the `PLEASE ADD YOUR COLUMNS HERE` to show your columns and we can help from there :)

Comment: You'll need to do a `JOIN` on the two table to connect the data for the query. but to know how to write the query, we need to know what column connects the two tables. For example, presumably, your `videos` table has a `userId` column or similar that stores the id of the user that uploaded the video. We just need to know what that column is called exactly

Comment: @WesleySmith

Ok the queues I use is a `username` in users

And the other queues are: `name`, `thumbnail`, `type`, `quality`, `title_id`, `updated_at`

Comment: `FROM videos, users` is a very old syntax for joining tables. It has been made redundant in 1992 when explicit joins got introduced in the SQL standard. **Please don't use this old syntax.** As your query has no `WHERE` clause, there is no restriction on which rows to join with which others. Nowadays we write this as `FROM videos CROSS JOIN users`. You are combining every video row with every user row. As you want to join every video only with its related user, you need an `INNER JOIN` instead and an `INNER JOIN` needs an `ON` clause to specify the relation. See Wesley's answer on this.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) clause

This should work for you:

```
SELECT 
    u.username,
    v.name, 
    v.thumbnail, 
    v.type, 
    v.quality, 
    v.title_id, 
    v.updated_at
FROM
    videos v
        JOIN
    users u ON v.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY v.id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

If you wanted to join more tables, you'd just need to add another appropriate JOIN clause, as an example:

```
SELECT 
    u.username,
    v.name, 
    v.thumbnail, 
    v.type, 
    v.quality, 
    v.title_id, 
    v.updated_at,
    sot.some_column
FROM
    videos v
        JOIN
    users u ON v.user_id = u.id
        JOIN
    someOtherTable sot ON sot.type = v.type
ORDER BY v.id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Hello, if I want to make into three tables? how do I do it?

Comment: @רויטלבןשמעון You'd just add another join clause like `JOIN someOtherTable sot ON sot.type = v.type`, and any columns you want from the new table, see example

Comment: $sql = "SELECT u.username, v.name, v.thumbnail, v.type, v.quality, v.title_id, v.updated_at, v.season, v.episode, v.category, sot.name FROM videos v JOIN users u ON v.user_id = u.id JOIN roles sot on sot.name = u.id ORDER BY v.id DESC LIMIT 15";

thi si no working  :(

Comment: @רויטלבןשמעון How are `users` related to `roles` exactly? I would think that rolse->users would be a many to many relationship with a mapping table between them, something like `user_has_roles`, do you know if thats the case here or do they share a common column like the videos->users relation?

Comment: Even if the name is different, it does not show me anything.
The table roles there are names of groups that are related to certain people, the table name is name but in video there is also the name name so maybe it conflicts but I put your code, so it writes to me "No records matching your query were found." there is a solution?

Comment: "The table roles there are names of groups that are related to certain people," yes exactly. But _how_ are those tables related? the user's table you showed doesnt have a `role_id` or similar column so Im assuming there's a mapping/pivot table that relates the two? If thats the case, what is the name of that table and its columns?

Comment: In this picture you will see another table, I want to link only the name "name".
https://prnt.sc/upmzdg